# Showing data between date and loop through the years

Tags: mysql

Am trying to write a query that will return all the data that the start date and end date of the task falls between the posted date, and if the start date is set but the ending date is `0000-00-00` then the data will keep appearing in the result since it does not have an end date. Also, the results should show apart from the current week that week that we are in i.e `NOW()`. so if we compare the week of the posted date and the current week and the posted date week is higher, the the result should come up.

My database structure looks like this:

```
id  cons_id     day_name        start_date      end_date        status_code
___________________________________________________________________________
1   105         Wednesday       2017-05-17      0000-00-00      0
2   106         Wednesday       2017-05-24      2018-06-20      0
3   107         Thursday        2017-05-25      2030-02-28      0
4   108         Friday          2017-05-19      2019-01-25      0
5   109         Wednesday       2018-01-03      2018-02-14      0
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT i.cons_id AS 'cons_id',
                i.type AS 'type',
                i.day_name AS 'day_name',
                i.day_num AS 'day_num',
                i.start_date AS 'start_date',
                i.end_date AS 'end_date',
                i.created_at AS 'created_at',
                i.updated_at AS 'updated_at'
                FROM recurent_cons AS i
                WHERE i.status_code = '0'
                AND ('2017-05-26' BETWEEN i.start_date AND i.end_date)
                AND i.end_date >= '2017-05-26'
                OR i.end_date = '0000-00-00'
```

the query above shows the record with `id` 1 even in the current week which is not right, also when i change a date to year `2018`, it does not show records for this year `2017` which the end date of the record is for `2018`

so the result will be something like this:

if i pick 2017-05-24, i should see:

```
id  cons_id     day_name        start_date      end_date        status_code
```

---

```
1   105         Wednesday       2017-05-17      0000-00-00      0
3   107         Thursday        2017-05-25      2030-02-28      0
5   109         Wednesday       2018-01-03      2018-02-14      0
```

which excludes its current date and shows the future dates plus the infinity one (`0000-00-00`)

Comment: Pls provide how the expected output should look like because I simply do not understand what you are after based on this.

Comment: Could you show the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The last `OR i.end_date = '0000-00-00'` is true for the entry with `id=1` this why it's shows up in your query result.

You probably wanted to do this:

```
SELECT i.cons_id AS 'cons_id',
       i.type AS 'type',
       i.day_name AS 'day_name',
       i.day_num AS 'day_num',
       i.start_date AS 'start_date',
       i.end_date AS 'end_date',
       i.created_at AS 'created_at',
       i.updated_at AS 'updated_at'
FROM recurent_cons AS i
WHERE i.status_code = '0'
    AND ('2017-05-26' BETWEEN i.start_date AND i.end_date)
    AND (i.end_date >= '2017-05-26' OR i.end_date = '0000-00-00')
```

If you want all entries that are in the current date, the future or didn't end yet:

```
SELECT i.cons_id AS 'cons_id',
       i.type AS 'type',
       i.day_name AS 'day_name',
       i.day_num AS 'day_num',
       i.start_date AS 'start_date',
       i.end_date AS 'end_date',
       i.created_at AS 'created_at',
       i.updated_at AS 'updated_at'
FROM recurent_cons AS i
WHERE i.status_code = '0' 

    AND (i.start_date >='2017-05-26' # Future and current
         OR i.end_date = '0000-00-00') # Didn't finish yet
```

Comment: when i do this then the infinity one does not appear at all

Comment: Well I don't know what exactly your goal/task is here, but in your post you said it should not appear when you select the current month and now you want it to show up? I'm a little bit confused now. 
Maybe you need to provide more context.

Comment: i have posted a sample result